# Convert Arabic Text to Hex C#

Tags: c#, pos

I am building POS Application that print Arabic words into a receipt printer. I used Lprinter class to send printing commands to the printer. my problem is that I can not print Arabic directly to the printer, so after multiple workarounds and search, I found a way to print Arabic on my printer. First I made couple modifiaction to Lprinter class where I changed

```
 CharSet.Ansi
```

to

```
CharSet.Auto
```

also, I copied the print method and changed `Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi` to `Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni`. so when I print Arabic, I would call the new method.

This is actually worked for me. now I am trying to convert Arabic text to hex in order to send it to the printer.

I tried the following:

```
 byte[] bytes1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("ا");
        Array.Reverse(bytes1);
        var hexString = BitConverter.ToString(bytes1);
        hexString = hexString.Replace("-", "");


        MyPrinter.PrintAr(hexString);
```

However, I get the actual hex, as I could not insert \x to allow the printer identify that this is hex rather than text.
FYI, when I send

```
MyPrinter.PrintAr("\xFEEF\xFE8F\xFEA3");
```

it actually print Arabic.

I would really appreciate your help in how I could accurately transform Arabic text to hex and then add \x or \u before each hex.

Below is the LPrinter class after modification:

```
  class LPrinter
{
    // Structure and API declarions:
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] public string pDocName;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] public string pOutputFile;
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] public string pDataType;
    }
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterW", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterW", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

    /*=================================================*/

    private IntPtr HandlePrinter;
    private PrinterSettings ps;

    public LPrinter()
    {
        HandlePrinter = IntPtr.Zero;
        ps = new PrinterSettings();
    }

    public string PrinterName
    {
        get
        {
            return ps.PrinterName;
        }
        set
        {
            ps.PrinterName = value;
        }
    }

    public bool ChoosePrinter()
    {
        PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
        pd.PrinterSettings = ps;
        if (pd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            ps = pd.PrinterSettings;
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public bool Open(string DocName)
    {
        // see if printer is already open
        if (HandlePrinter != IntPtr.Zero) return false;

        // opens the printer
        bool risp = OpenPrinter(ps.PrinterName, out HandlePrinter, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (risp == false) return false;

        // starts a print job
        DOCINFOA MyDocInfo = new DOCINFOA();
        MyDocInfo.pDocName = DocName;
        MyDocInfo.pOutputFile = null;
        MyDocInfo.pDataType = "RAW";

        if (StartDocPrinter(HandlePrinter, 1, MyDocInfo))
        {
            StartPagePrinter(HandlePrinter); //starts a page       
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }

    public bool Close()
    {
        if (HandlePrinter == IntPtr.Zero) return false;
        if (!EndPagePrinter(HandlePrinter)) return false;
        if (!EndDocPrinter(HandlePrinter)) return false;
        if (!ClosePrinter(HandlePrinter)) return false;
        HandlePrinter = IntPtr.Zero;
        return true;
    }

    public bool Print(string outputstring)
    {
        if (HandlePrinter == IntPtr.Zero) return false;

         //IntPtr buf = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(outputstring);
         IntPtr buf = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni(outputstring);

        Int32 done = 0;
        bool ok = WritePrinter(HandlePrinter, buf, outputstring.Length, out done);

        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buf);

        if (!ok) return false;
        else return true;
    }

    public bool PrintAr(string outputstring)
    {
        if (HandlePrinter == IntPtr.Zero) return false;

        // IntPtr buf = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(outputstring);
        IntPtr buf = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemUni(outputstring);

        Int32 done = 0;
        bool ok = WritePrinter(HandlePrinter, buf, outputstring.Length, out done);

        Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(buf);

        if (!ok) return false;
        else return true;
    }


}
```

Comment: You should use `OpenPrinterW` not `OpenPrinterA` Never never never use the A versions. Unicode all the way.

Comment: Ben thanks for your comment, When I replaced it with `OpenPrinterW`, the printer did not print anything.

Comment: You have to make all the relevant changes: `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWstr)` and so forth.

Comment: Thanks Ben, the printer started to response, but still I can not print Arabic.

Comment: Have you changed everything to Unicode? All the marshalAs, all the types, all the struct fields? All the function names to W? Unicode all the way.

Comment: Yes I tried twice, and still the same issue.

Comment: So show your current code.

Comment: I have updated LPrinter class as per your recommendation and post it on the question. please check and let me know if I miss any.

Comment: What if send hexString.Replace(“-“, “\\x”); or try to split string every 4 character and then join with “\\x”..

Comment: Almost there, now you have to use UTF-16 not UTF-8 `Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes`

Comment: Thanks guys, I am able now to add the \x to my hex, but I could not get the right hex code for Arabic. I used Unicode but I think I am missing something